# Cross-site WooCommerce implementation

Tags: rest-api, headless

I have two WordPress websites.

On the **first** one I installed and configured WooCommerce, everything is working as expected with a custom theme, several plugins and so on.

The **second** one, with custom theme too, has no WooCommerce installed.

Now I need to integrate each other in a way that some of the products listed on the **first** appear on the **second**, then the user could sign in, put listed products in cart, view cart, checkout and even subscribe navigating the **second** but using the WooCommerce installed on the **first**.

I guess I can reach this goal using REST API and a sort of headless architecture.

- Do you see any kind of cons, blocking points or reasons why I shouldn't go down this path?
- Are all the informations I need to recreate the templates on the **second** website (including product archives, single product, checkout, cart, user area and so on...) easily retrievable via API from the **first** assuming I'm quite confident in creating REST API routes and endpoints?
- What about payments processing, considering I use Stripe and Paypal Payments on the **first** website as gateways?